# openni and ar bounding box doesn't work well together

Tags: openni, roboearth, openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm working with the RoboEarth package to model 3D Objects. The results were mediocre and because of that we tried to calibrate our kinect. (using this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera/calibration)

We found out that there is a second (seems to be the newer one) launch file for the openni (the old and original one: openni_camera openni_node.launch | the new one: openni_launch openni.launch) which is needed for the calibration.
But it seems that the ar-bounding-box package is not working with that file. Could this be true?

Furthermore we noticed that the ar_bounding_box is not working reliable with the old launch file (openni_camera) as well. Sometimes it takes 5-10 restarts to get it run. Do you have any idea to correct that?

Thank you for your help.
regards Ronny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11941/openni-and-ar-bounding-box-doesn%27t-work-well-together/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We just updated the roboearth packages so that you can use the launch files from the openni_launch package. Please update to the latest version and try again.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1